# Change placeholder text for filter search in Ant Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is there any way I can change the default placeholder text in Ant Table? I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/filter-search-antd-5-14-1-forked-yx6jpz?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90006356kds2438mn%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90002356klh3a1uip%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90003356knsmor8g5%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90005356khms99wqp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clswcohb90002356klh3a1uip%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90002356klh3a1uip%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clswcohb90005356khms99wqp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90004356kzgy4hg0b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90005356khms99wqp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90004356kzgy4hg0b%2522%257D%252C%2522clswcohb90003356knsmor8g5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clswcohb90003356knsmor8g5%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). Could anyone please advise?

I checked the Ant design [documentation](https://ant.design/components/table) if there is any prop to customize it but didn't find any apart from the whole customized filter dropdown which I didn't want to create it.

Below is column configuration from my code.

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    filters: [
      {
        text: "London",
        value: "London",
      },
      {
        text: "New York",
        value: "New York",
      },
    ],
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.startsWith(value),
    filterSearch: true,
    width: "40%",
  },
];

...

const App = () => (
  <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />
);
```

Image for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Table>` component can be passed the `locale` prop with type

```
export interface TableLocale {
  filterTitle?: string;
  filterConfirm?: React.ReactNode;
  filterReset?: React.ReactNode;
  filterEmptyText?: React.ReactNode;
  filterCheckall?: React.ReactNode;
  filterSearchPlaceholder?: string;
  emptyText?: React.ReactNode | (() => React.ReactNode);
  selectAll?: React.ReactNode;
  selectNone?: React.ReactNode;
  selectInvert?: React.ReactNode;
  selectionAll?: React.ReactNode;
  sortTitle?: string;
  expand?: string;
  collapse?: string;
  triggerDesc?: string;
  triggerAsc?: string;
  cancelSort?: string;
}
```

The relevant part is `filterSearchPlaceholder`.

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  onChange={onChange}
  locale={{
    filterSearchPlaceholder: 'put anything here'
  }}
/>
```